# How to find TextBox ID inside EditFormSettings using jquery

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

```
<EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template" PopUpSettings-Width="80%">

                    <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>

                    <FormTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" Text='<%# Bind( "last_name") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"> </asp:TextBox>
                     </FormTemplate>
    </EditFormSettings>
```

How Can I get TextBox(txtLastName) id from Client Site

Answer (score 0):

To find any control inside `template/itemtemplate` you need to find the element by **[attributeEndsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)**.

As when the textbox renders the  clientID of the textbox is assign at the last of the id attribute(which is dynamically generated) of the rendered control (in your case textbox)

```
var txtLastNameID=$("[id$='txtLastName']").attr("id");// will give you id(dynamically generated)

var txtLastNameI=$("[id$='txtLastName']");// will give you object of control
```